# React Component event handler function did not received the newest value from Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a simple app as my side project just to understand React and Redux more. I found a problem when invoking async action creator which updated the value in the reducer but when I try to access the value in the component event-handler function, it still has the old value.

Here's my action creator:

```
export const assignUsername = username => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: types.ASSIGN_USERNAME_REQUEST})

  await axios({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "/v1/user/username",
    data: {
      username: username
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    if(response.data && response.data.success){
      dispatch({
        type: types.ASSIGN_USERNAME_SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data.result
      })
    }else{
      dispatch({type: types.ASSIGN_USERNAME_FAILED})
      dispatch(httpPopUpError(response.status, response.data.message))
    }
  })
}
```

Here's the reducer:

```
var initialState = {
  loading: false,
  result: null,
  error: false
};

function AuthReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ASSIGN_USERNAME_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: false
      }
    case types.ASSIGN_USERNAME_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: true
      }
    case types.ASSIGN_USERNAME_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        result: action.payload,
        error: false
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here's the event handler function which invoking the action creator and accessing the store:

```
  handleAssignUsername = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    formValidator(this.state.form)
      .then(validatedForm => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          form: validatedForm
        }, () => {
          this.props.assignUsername(this.state.form.username.value)
          .then(() => {
            if(!this.props.AuthReducer.error) {
              this.props.history.push("/")
            }
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(errorForm => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          form: errorForm
        })
      })
  }
```

As you can see above, I access the "this.props.AuthReducer.error" tp determine whether it has an error or not then decide to redirect. But, the error value still *false* although in Redux Devtools I saw it already turns to *true*

I really appreciated it if anyone could help, or maybe suggest a more elegant approach if mine is not a proper approach. Thank you.

note: 
I have try a similar approach in my other project and it works fine. That's what makes me confuse because sometimes it works, sometimes don't.

**EDIT:**
I tried the suggestion from **Hemanath** but when I console log the error, it still has the same value even if the error turns to *true* in the Store.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  console.log(prevProps.AuthReducer.error, "PREV");
  console.log(this.props.AuthReducer.error, "NOW");
  if(prevProps.AuthReducer.error === false && this.props.AuthReducer.error === true){
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
}
```

[The screenshot of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMURP.png)
And about redirecting in render method, I'm afraid that is not a good approach since the default value of the **error** is FALSE, if I do it then it will always redirect.

I want to do the AJAX request first then redirect if the error is still false.

Answer (score 1):

use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to watch for the `this.props.AuthReducer.error` value change and redirect from there based on the new value,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(prevProps.AuthReducer.error === false && this.props.AuthReducer.error === true){
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
}
```

or as suggested in the comment you can use the `Redirect` component from `react-router` in the `render` method to redirect, like this

```
render() {
    const { AuthReducer } = this.props;
    if (AuthReducer && AuthReducer.loading === false && AuthReducer.error === true) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />;
    }
    return (
      <div>....</div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can redirect in render method instead and dont check prevProps at all?

Comment: I tried it, I console.log the error from prevProps and this.props it still print the same value which is false (the old value) after I click on the submit button which invokes the event handler function. When I start typing again, then it prints true (the newest value)

Comment: @D.Richard sure it will work, but is it the best approach?

Comment: Yes thats why I am telling you.

Comment: @D.Richard I'm afraid that it won't work after I think about it since the default value of the error is FALSE, it will always redirect the user when accessing the page if I put the redirect in render method. I need to do the AJAX first, then decide to redirect if the error still false

Comment: return <Redirect to='/' />; is MUCH cleaner than this.props.history.push("/");

Comment: can you elaborate more on it? I don't quite get it. If the error is TRUE I don't want to redirect, I want to redirect if the error is FALSE (the default error is FALSE)